# How to calculate physical address in computer architecture?

Tags: memory, cpu-architecture

I am not able to understand how to calculate physical memory address. How two 16 bit registers combine together to generate 20 bit address? What is the mechanism? Look we have a segment of memory consisting of maximum 64K? Right? In that particular segment what goes on? How registers act to calculate the physical address?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're asking about calculating addresses on old 16-bit x86 systems.  The way that worked was that you took the segment register and shifted it up by four (i.e. multiplied by 16) and then added that to the register.  So, if CS was 0x1111 and AX was 0x1111, then the physical address would be 0x12221.